# How does a cameras focus affect its camera matrix and distortion coefficients

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I’m using a raspberry pi camera 3 that has autofocus to track aruco markers.

In order to do this I need accurate distortion coefficients and camera matrix.

How will the autofocus affect this? Do I need to lock the autofocus and then calibrate the camera at that focus? Or should the matrix and coefficients be the same no matter the focus of the camera?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: To my knowledge, focus shouldn't sffect intrinsics too much, but zoom would! But I can't tell in values. Afair there is at least one research paper about this.